Return the XML node name using all occurrences of a defined value for each row
I have this CLOB column on a table, which is filled with XML data.
This predefined string can possibly be the value of multiple nodes per each row.
The purpose is simply to get a report in which XML nodes are affected.
Say, this is row ID 10 with CLOB_XML
<personInfo>
<name>Blank</name>
<addressGroup>
<town>Cape</town>
<city>Blank</city>
</addressGroup>
</personInfo>

How can I return like so:



Row ID
CLOB_XML




10
<personInfo><name>Blank</name></personInfo>


10
<addressGroup><city>Blank</city></addressGroup>



Tried INSTR - didn't seem to be able to catch multiple occurrences.
EVALSTRING only gets the value - I need to search node provided the value

I don't understand your output - some of that might be formatting (you can escape angle-brackets with backslashes; or format as code rather than a proper table) but it looks mangled beyond just that; and where is the 'Row ID' value coming from? You've shown a single fragment, that isn't a complete XML document, but you refer to multiple nodes. So it's all quite unclear. Please provide a [mcve]. Why are you using instr - assuming your real data is valid XML, why not use the built-in XML functions - probably XMLTable in this case?

Reformatted the post. Basically, I want to read the whole xml, return all the nodes and its parent node which have a value same as the specified string

If you want the XML with only the matching nodes then you can use a FLWOR expression to delete the non-matching leaf nodes:
SELECT t.id, x.xml.getClobVal() AS xml
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         'copy $j := /.
          modify
          (
            for $i in $j//*[not(text()="Blank" or *)]
               return delete node $i
          )
          return $j
         '
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value)
         COLUMNS 
            xml XMLTYPE PATH '/.'
       ) x;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 10, EMPTY_CLOB() || '<personInfo>
<name>Blank</name>
<addressGroup>
<town>Cape</town>
<city>Blank</city>
</addressGroup>
</personInfo>' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
XML




10
<personInfo><name>Blank</name><addressGroup><city>Blank</city></addressGroup></personInfo>




If you want the parent elements and to delete the non-matching child nodes then:
SELECT t.id, x.xml.getClobVal() AS xml
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '//*[text()="Blank"]/..'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value)
         COLUMNS 
            xml XMLTYPE PATH 'copy $j := .
              modify
              (
                for $i in $j/*[not(text()="Blank") or *]
                  return delete node $i
              )
              return $j'
       ) x;

Which outputs:



ID
XML




10
<personInfo><name>Blank</name></personInfo>


10
<addressGroup><city>Blank</city></addressGroup>



or, modifying Alex Poole's solution but using a copy of the parent node and child nodes and combining them in a FLWOR expression (which will preserve the parent and child's attributes):
SELECT t.id,
       x.xml.getClobVal() AS xml
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '//*[text()="Blank"]'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value)
         COLUMNS 
            xml XMLTYPE PATH 
              'copy $child := ., $parent := ..
              modify
              (
                for $node in $parent/*
                  return delete node $node,
                insert node $child into $parent
              )
              return $parent'
       ) x;

Which, for the sample data would output the same.
fiddle

I am trying this out but getting a result of (XMLTYPE) in both query result and script output. I did check the Display XML value in grid in Preferences. Is this somehow related to how big the data in the CLOB is? It's pretty huge (over 300,000 chars)

@karmachameleon It is returning an XMLTYPE but the client application you use to make the query can often view it for you by double-clicking or right-clicking on the XMLTYPE value. If you always want it as a CLOB then use x.xml.getClobVal() to apply the conversion in the query.

You can start with XMLTABLE query:
with data(id, xml) as (
    select 1, xmltype(q'~<root><name>Blank</name>
<addressGroup>
<town>Cape</town>
<city>Blank</city>
</addressGroup></root>~')
)
select id, gparent, parent, name from 
data d, xmltable('//*/.'
        passing d.xml
        columns 
            gparent varchar2(64) path '../../name()',
            parent varchar2(64) path '../name()',
            name varchar2(64) path 'name()',
            content varchar2(4000) path 'text()'
    ) t1
where content = 'Blank'
;

And - not very clear what you expect exactly - add the formatting  you want on the results.

from what I understood this syntax requires to at least define the level of the node, as seen in gparent and parent... What if the element with the specified value resides deeper or within a list? It could be anywhere

If you just wanted the nodes with that value you could get them with a filtered wildcard XPath in an XMLTable call:
select t.id, x.node
from your_table t
cross join xmltable('//*[text()="Blank"]'
  passing xmltype(t.clob_xml)
  columns
    node xmltype path '.'
) x




ID
NODE




10
<name>Blank</name>


10
<city>Blank</city>



But you want the parent node too. If you just wanted the node names you could do that directly too:
select t.id, x.parent_name, x.name, x.text
from your_table t
cross join xmltable('//*[text()="Blank"]'
  passing xmltype(t.clob_xml)
  columns
    parent_name varchar2(4000) path '../name()',
    name varchar2(4000) path 'name()',
    text varchar2(4000) path 'text()'
) x




ID
PARENT_NAME
NAME
TEXT




10
personInfo
name
Blank


10
addressGroup
city
Blank



But you want the node structure - and without other sibling/child nodes. So you could recreate the nodes from that data:
select t.id,
  xmlelement(evalname x.parent_name,
    xmlelement(evalname x.name, x.text)).getclobval() as clob_xml
from your_table t
cross join xmltable('//*[text()="Blank"]'
  passing xmltype(t.clob_xml)
  columns
    parent_name varchar2(4000) path '../name()',
    name varchar2(4000) path 'name()',
    text varchar2(4000) path 'text()'
) x




ID
CLOB_XML




10
<personInfo><name>Blank</name></personInfo>


10
<addressGroup><city>Blank</city></addressGroup>



fiddle
(This won't preserve attributes, but you haven't shown any, and might not them if you do have any.)
